# How to convert unpacked array to single value using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, unpack

I am trying to convert unpacked value of 4 byte array? Is this possible in Ruby?

say I wrote `b1 = b.unpack("N")` and print value of `b1` which is `1` . But when I try to convert b1 to some integer using .to_i console throws error `test.rb:13: undefined method`to_i' for [118]:Array (NoMethodError)`

My code is following:

```
File.open('testfile','rb') do |file|
file.read.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*\w)(.{8})/).each do |a,b,c,d,e|
    if a == "cook"
    puts "test1"
    else
    puts "test2"
    end
    puts "output1"
    b1 = b.unpack("N")
    puts "output2"
    c1 = c.unpack("N")
    puts "output3"
    puts "output4"
    puts "output5"
end
end
```

Comment: `b1` is an array; what would `to_i` mean? If you want it as an integer, you'd need to use `b1[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) always returns an array, even if there's only one value:

```
irb:01> s = "\x0\x0\x0*"
#=> "\u0000\u0000\u0000*"

irb:02> v = s.unpack('N')
#=> [42]

irb:03> v.class
#=> Array
```

You are confused because when you `puts` an array it outputs the `to_s` version of each value on its own line; in this case that *looks* like a single number:

```
irb:04> puts v
#=> 42

irb:05> puts [1,2,3]
#=> 1
#=> 2
#=> 3
```

In the future, when debugging your programs through print statements, use `p` instead of `puts`, as the output of it is similar to source code and designed to be clear:

```
irb:12> puts 42, "42", [42]
#=> 42
#=> 42
#=> 42

irb:13> p 42, "42", [42]
#=> 42
#=> "42"
#=> [42]
```

As @Dave commented, you need to extract the integer from the array to really use it as an integer:

```
irb:06> i = v.first  # or v[0]
#=> 42

irb:07> i.class
#=> Fixnum
```